# Adding cert to trusted certs

Tags: windows-7, ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I'm trying to access a web service from a certain website.

Since this is a service I can't just click somewhere "go to this site anyway". I just get an endpoint exception in my code.

I downloaded the certificate from my browser and it appeared to have the name "DigiCert High Assurance CA-3"

When I added it to my certificates in the Windows7 MMC I saw a bunch of other DigitCert variants, but not the one I thought I imported.

The browser is still throwing a certificate problem when I go to that IP.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I imported the cert to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" directory in the Windows certificates manager.

EDIT EDIT:

I came back to my browser the next day and all of the sudden it liked this URL. Strange. Too peculiar to put "go play 18 rounds and come back later" as the correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure the certificate you’re trying to import actually represents a root certificate authority and not an intermediate certificate authority?

Comment: @Daniel B: How could I inspect that? I don't see anything when I r-click->properties ...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @micahhoover You need to “Open” the certificate by double-clicking. [Here’s how certificates look like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TSxWL.png), from left to right: Root CA, Intermediate CA, Server. You can easily ascertain the type by inspecting the chain and subject of a certificate.

Comment: @Cubia: Chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: @DanielB: Thanks. Under the details tab I see "CN = agency-api-integration.fnf.com
OU = FNF - AgentTrax
O = Fidelity National Financial, Inc.
L = Jacksonville
S = Florida
C = US" But I don't see anything labelled "chain". There appears to be a hierarchical certification path: "DigiCert->DigiCert High Assurance CA-3->agency-api-integration.fnf.com" Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after installing the certificate myself, it appeared in Intermediate Certificate Authorities, as expected.

If I were to venture a guess, I’d say there’s something else going on, like a name mismatch. DigiCert is trusted by Windows. A properly configured server will ship intermediate certificates and the chain of trust is established.

Seeing how I can’t access the host myself, you’ll have to figure it out yourself. As mentioned, it’s very likely there’s a host name mismatch: `agency-api-integration.fnf.com` is what’s expected. Other likely causes are an expired certificate or an improperly configured host (not shipping intermediate certificates).

Some general advice:
When adding the certificates snap-in to your MMC, I recommend using the “Computer Account” option, so the change will be available for all users (and Windows services).